# WPF equivalent to Silverlight "RootVisual"

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am trying to port an application from silverlight to wpf. Unfortunatley I am new to both. Is there an equvivalent to the following Silverlight code in WPF?

```
        private static Canvas GetCanvas()
        {
            var uc = Application.Current.RootVisual as UserControl;
            if (uc == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return uc.FindName("ChoiceCanvas") as Canvas;
        }
```

Currently I am using

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("ChoiceCanvas") as Canvas;
```

But this doesn't work, perhaps because ChoiceCanvas is something located in a UserControl and not in the MainWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindName won't work becuase the Canvas exists in the namescope of the UserControl, try using the LogicalTreeHelper instead.

```
 var canvas = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(
      Application.Current.MainWindow, "ChoiceCanvas") as Canvas;
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no RootVisual property in WPF.  As far as I understand, the "Window" is the "root".  You can get the Window that any WPF (D.O.) object belongs to by running the static method Window myWindow = [Window.GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow.aspx)(myControl);

Answer (score 1):

The current window is the root visual.

From MSDN [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#visual_tree):

> The **root visual** is the top-most element in a visual tree hierarchy. In
>   most applications, the base class of the root visual is either **Window**
>   or NavigationWindow. However, if you were hosting visual objects in a
>   Win32 application, the root visual would be the top-most visual you
>   were hosting in the Win32 window. For more information, see Tutorial:
>   Hosting Visual Objects in a Win32 Application.